# How to control dashes of the edge in matplotlib fill_between function?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I've been recently using the matplotlib's `fill_between` function to plot rectangles with dashed edges. For example this one is located between t1, t2, fmin and fmax :

```
ax.fill_between([t1, t2], fmin, fmax, facecolor=(0, 0, 0, 0), linestyle='--)
```

I know it is possible to specify the dash on-off sequence in the `plot` function with the keyword argument `dashes=[6, 2]`, for instance, but this does not work with `fill_between`. I had a look at the `fill_between()` [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=fill_between#matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between), but I did not find any solution.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was going to be a comment, but it doesn't seem to format well.

Looking at the code, it appears the fill_between returns a PolyCollection, as a opposed to a Line2D object that uses dashes keyword as you mentioned above.  The PolyCollection class doesn't actually save the edge lines as a Line2D class (which is probably good for optimization reasons).  This means that even though the edges are drawn like lines, you don't have to full flexibility as you do with the Line2D class.  The PolyCollection seems to be missing this code:

```
def _draw_dashed(self, renderer, gc, path, trans):
    gc.set_linestyle('dashed')
    if self._dashSeq is not None:
        gc.set_dashes(0, self._dashSeq)
```

In particular, there is no *set_dashes* code in the draw method of the PolyCollection.  To implement this, tt appears you would require a way for setting a dash sequence variable in your PolyCollection instance and then calling *gc.set_dashes(dash_seq)* during the draw command.

I dont see any way to hook (inject) this code into the PolyCollection without modifying the source code.  So perhaps this is best reported as a feature request in the matplotlib github.  It seems like a reasonable request to be able to control the dash-sequence of edges, but this might be more complicated than initial glance because then you would have to synchronize this sequence between each individual edge (in the general case) which might not be worth it.

However, you might find it better to write a new function to draw your squares instead of using the fill_between function since that is not what it's meant for.  With a personal function you can use Line2D objects.

EDIT: If you do happen to ask matplotlib on github, let me know what they say.  They may actually say that you can inject code in the draw command with proper subclassing.  I would have to think about it some more.